# Entity Framework Linq Query Plus Sql Function Nested Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following linq query

```
public IEnumerable<DealershipWithDealersViewModel> Get(float latitude, float longitude)
        {
            return from dealer in Db.Dealerships
                          join i in Db.NearestDealers(latitude, longitude)
                          on dealer.DealerID equals i.DealerID
                          select new DealershipWithDealersViewModel
                                     {
                                         DealerID = dealer.DealerID,
                                         Dealer = dealer.Dealer,
                                         DoSales = dealer.DoSales,
                                         DoService = dealer.DoService,
                                         AddressProvinceID = dealer.AddressProvinceID,
                                         AddressLocationID = dealer.AddressLocationID,
                                         Address1 = dealer.Address1,
                                         Address2 = dealer.Address2,
                                         Tel = dealer.Tel,
                                         Fax = dealer.Fax,
                                         MapLat = dealer.MapLat,
                                         MapLong = dealer.MapLong,
                                         Location = dealer.Location.LocationName,
                                         DealerUsers = dealer.DealerUsers
                                            .Select(y => new DealerUserViewModel
                                                             {
                                                                DealerUserID = y.DealerUserID,
                                                                FirstName  = y.Firstname,
                                                                Surname = y.Surname,
                                                                LandLine = y.LandLine,
                                                                Email = y.Email,
                                                                Position = y.DealerType.DealerPosition
                                                             })

                                     };
        }
```

[image]
I keep getting the following error **The nested query does not have the appropriate keys**. I cannot find anything about it on the net. If I load the above without DealerUsers, it works as expected, but I need the nested data. Thank you! The below works by the way.

```
public IEnumerable<DealershipWithDealersViewModel> Get(float latitude, float longitude)
        {
            return from dealer in Db.Dealerships
                          join i in Db.NearestDealers(latitude, longitude)
                          on dealer.DealerID equals i.DealerID
                          select new DealershipWithDealersViewModel
                                     {
                                         DealerID = dealer.DealerID,
                                         Dealer = dealer.Dealer,
                                         DoSales = dealer.DoSales,
                                         DoService = dealer.DoService,
                                         AddressProvinceID = dealer.AddressProvinceID,
                                         AddressLocationID = dealer.AddressLocationID,
                                         Address1 = dealer.Address1,
                                         Address2 = dealer.Address2,
                                         Tel = dealer.Tel,
                                         Fax = dealer.Fax,
                                         MapLat = dealer.MapLat,
                                         MapLong = dealer.MapLong,
                                         Location = dealer.Location.LocationName

                                     };
        }
```

[image]

**Update**

This also works.

```
return Db.Dealerships.Select(x => new DealershipWithDealersViewModel
            {
                DealerID = x.DealerID,
                Dealer = x.Dealer,
                DoSales = x.DoSales,
                DoService = x.DoService,
                AddressProvinceID = x.AddressProvinceID,
                AddressLocationID = x.AddressLocationID,
                Address1 = x.Address1,
                Address2 = x.Address2,
                Tel = x.Tel,
                Fax = x.Fax,
                MapLat = x.MapLat,
                MapLong = x.MapLong,
                Location = x.Location.Location1,
                DealerUsers = x.DealerUsers.Select(y => new DealerUserViewModel
                                                            {
                                                                DealerUserID = y.DealerUserID,
                                                                FirstName = y.Firstname,
                                                                Surname = y.Surname,
                                                                LandLine = y.LandLine,
                                                                Email = y.Email,
                                                                Position = y.DealerType.DealerType1
                                                            })
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I am. Entity Framework 5.

Comment: can you try `DealerID = dealer.DealerId` instead of `DealerID = i.DealerId`?

Comment: I did and makes no difference. Kinda stumped on this one. Will update the answer so people are not confused.

Comment: What happens in `Db.NearestDealers(latitude, longitude)`?

Comment: It is a sql function that calculates the nearest dealers based on their Latitude and Longitude values.

Comment: I attached screenshots.

Comment: OK. Does `dealer.DealerUsers` work in a separate simple query on Dealerships?

Comment: Ya, check updated answer. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of composablity. EF will always try to translate your query into SQL. If this succeeds, fine. If it doesn't, it's not going to try and make it work e.g. by switching to linq to objects below the hood (as linq to sql may do). You trying to join a stored procedure result to a SQL query. This can't even be done in plains SQL, because sproc results are not composable, let alone by EF.

You van only join the results in memory, by using `Db.Dealerships.AsEnumerable()` and `Db.NearestDealers(latitude, longitude)`.

So it would be very useful if you could add a filter parameter `DealerID` to the procedure's signature.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just ended up writing a stored procedure and bypassed the linq to sql completely.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing may not be possible. See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387167.aspx). At the bottom of the article it states

> Certain types of queries that require pulling up keys from a nested
>   query are not supported.